# Moviepy - Create multiple subclips using times from CSV file

Tags: python, video-processing, moviepy

I am creating a Python script which uses the MoviePy module, to take clips from a larger video and concatenate them together.

The times for the clips are detailed in a CSV file like so;

0,10

11,19

15,20

34,42
etc

What I have done is read the CSV file row by row and then using the subclip method from Moviepy created a clip which is stored in a list of clips, however I get a IndexError - list index out of range.

What could be the issue (the code works fine if I don't use the subclip method with the values from the CSV file)?

This is my code:

```
video= VideoFileClip('file')

clipsArray = [] 

import csv
with open('csv file', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        startTime = row[0]
        endTime = row[1]
        clip = fullVideo.subclip(startTime, endTime)
        clipsArray.append(clip)
```

The error message is:

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/spyder2-py3/program.py", line 32, in 
    clip = fullVideo.subclip(start, end) # Create clips for each of the timestamps

File "", line 2, in subclip

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 86, in wrapper
    for (arg, name) in zip(a, names)]

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\moviepy\decorators.py", line 86, in 
    for (arg, name) in zip(a, names)]

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\moviepy\tools.py", line 78, in cvsecs
    finds = re.findall(expr, time)[0]

IndexError: list index out of range

CSV file:

`0,12
16,21
22,29
34,59
89,130
140,160
162,171`

Comment: Please post your complete error message so that we can see where the error occurs.

Comment: @Zulko I have added the error message

Comment: It seems that the times in your CSV file are not formatted as MoviePy is expecting them. Can you paste some lines of your CSV file ?

Comment: @Zulko added a few lines

Comment: So I guess you want to add float(startTime), float(endTime) in subclip()

Comment: @Zulko hey that worked! Do want to add that as an answer so I can vote it? Could you tell me why the float() was needed?

Comment: @Zulko Hi, I have posted a new question re- your soccer_cuts.py script asking about what certain lines mean, and the easiest way to get mean volume of a clip. Would be grateful if you can provide an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it failed is because when you read from this csv file you get `startTime` and `endTime` as strings, for instance `'0'` and `'12'` in the first line.

MoviePy only accepts two formats for times:

- A numeric format (int or float) representing the number of seconds
- A string of the form `'hh:mm:ss.dd'` (hours, minutes, seconds, decimals of seconds), e.g. `'05:12:10.50'` for 5 hours 12 minutes and 10.5 seconds.

So you should write

```
startTime = float(row[0])
endTime = float(row[1])
clip = fullVideo.subclip(startTime, endTime)
```